# f bounded by an integrable function implies f is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I have been trying to prove that, for an arbitrary measure $\mu$:

$f\leq g$ almost everywhere, $g \in L_1 \implies$ $f$ is $\mu$-measurable.

I have had limited success with this proof so am starting to think that there exists a counterexample but have been unable to formulate one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\mu$-integrable? Then you'd need your $f \ge 0$ (or some variant of this) and the statement becomes true. Otherwise, I don't know why would anyone think that this statement is true

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take a nonmeasurable set $B\subseteq [0,1]$. Then $1_B$ is not measurable. However, $0 \leq 1_B \leq 1$ are integrable (on $[0,1]$) bounds on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterexample. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $g(x)=2$, which is clearly $L^1$. Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$, and let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\in A\\ 0 & x\not\in A.\end{cases}$$
Then $f\leq g$, but $f$ is certainly not measurable.